# start application knowing package name

Tags: android

How can i start a new application using its package name? I don't have information about what activity is the main one.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try using `PackageManager` and [`getLaunchIntentForPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String))

Comment: Sir Why cant i launch the Launcher by getting its package name its giving java.lang.NullPointer Exception?

Comment: Does launch a complete new Instance? I want to launch the existing one. How do I do that?

Comment: I would add the flags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED) to ensure the app state is the same if it was already opened.

Comment: I got a problem when i tried to pass extras to the target app. Only if the target app's process doesn't exist then it can get the extras or else it will get nothing.

Comment: Is this still a reliable solution after Package Visibility changes on Android 11?

Comment: @argenkiwi: I very rarely use this method. I expect that either it will work "out of the box", or you would need `<queries>` for a `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `Intent` structure. AFAIK, it is not completely broken.

Comment: @argenkiwi you mean android 12?

Comment: No, I meant Android 11 as per this section of the docs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

Answer (score 168):

Just use these following two lines, so you can launch any installed application whose package name is known:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.abc");
startActivity( launchIntent );
```

If you don't know the package name of application that you wanted to launch then try your hand on:

```
PackageManager pm;
pm = getPackageManager();
//  get a list of installed apps.
packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

For more information, refer to this link: [Using Package Manager](http://android-dev-sagarg.blogspot.in/2013/08/use-of-android-package-manager-for.html).

Comment: Does this launch a complete new Instance? I want to launch the existing one. How do I do that?

Comment: @hohny tex do you find a solution for your problem

Comment: @JohnyTex I know it's kind of late but you could try `LaunchIntent.setFlags("Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK");` and `LaunchIntent.setFlags("Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP");`

Comment: Is this still a reliable solution after Package Visibility changes on Android 11?

Comment: From Android 11, this will work only if use the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission. If you publish your app on Google Play, your app's use of this permission is subject to approval. https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility#intent-signature

Answer (score 23):

You can get the launch intent through the [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package");
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Note that [`getLaunchIntentForPackage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)) returns null if the package isn't found. So you might want to add a null check:

```
if (launchIntent != null) {
    context.startActivity(launchIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Package not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This answer is only very slightly different from the older answers, except that it's 3 years newer. I don't see how the upvotes are justified.

Comment: But at least he posted that the method returns null if no package, I was about to try catching activity not found exception.@hBrent

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent;                                        
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");                       
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("app.package.name");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    if (intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Package not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val packageName = "com.google.android.youtube"
var intent = activity!!.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)

          if (intent == null) {
            if (intent == null) {
                    intent = try {
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName"))
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageName"))
                    }
                }
             startActivity(intent)
```

For Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, in AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.youtube" />
    <package android:name="com.example.app" />
</queries>
```

Or simply we can allow for all packages (not recommended)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

References

[Package visibility filtering on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)