# Open third party app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app that uses packagenames to start a Third Party App. I have done some research and found out that all apps can be started from a launcher intent. Are there anyone that knows how to do this from a click of a Button.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422758/start-application-knowing-package-name

Comment: This is not a duplication. I ask how to start it and that question is how to find the packagename. I already know how to find the package name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't really 'start applications'. You can try to get the Launch Intent from the 3rd party application if you know the packagename:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.thirdparty.package");
startActivity( intent );
```

Comment: One should set the flags to "setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED)" to reopen already opened apps.

Answer (score 5):

For above accepted answer, if the third party app is not installed on your emulator, you should gracefully handle it also.
Here is a complete code for the same:

```
public void openThirdPartyApp() {   

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.thirdparty.package");
            intent.setPackage("com.thirdparty.package");

            try {
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                downloadIt();
            }
        }

    private void downloadIt() {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.thirdparty.package");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

                try {
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    //creates a small window to notify there is no app available 
                }   

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Good answear but this does not work with what I am doing. I am using a packagemanager that gets the package name and then start it. But this may be useful in later projects. Thanks for the answear!

Comment: This doesn't work... In the intent initialization code: Intent intent = new Intent("com.thirdparty.package"); there should be an action like "android.intent.action.MAIN" no?

Comment: @syonip, Why do you want to use "android.intent.action.MAIN" ??

Comment: According to the docs, an Intent constructor with a string argument, needs to receive and action, not a package name. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 2):

Just put it in an View.OnClickListener:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(theOtherActivityPackage);
        startActivity( intent );
    }
});
```