# How can i record the Android device screen?

Tags: android, screen, record, video-capture

I want to create an application that will enable the users to `Capture Screen` of their Android device. 
like any screen recorder software we used in pc please help me out

**Edit : 1**

here `Screen capture refers to Screen recording of device screen as video not snapshots of screen.`

Comment: You can't acheive this without root permission. Without root permission you are able to take screenshot of your own application only.

Comment: you mean to say like screen recorder ?

Comment: @ImranRana : thanks but tell me how to enable application recording

Comment: [Check this thread](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/951-how-to-capture-video-of-the-screen-on-android/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007247/how-to-record-screen-using-android-mediacodec

Comment: @SzaboBarna whats that

Comment: Android 4.4 added a shell command to record the screen.  See http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-screen-recording

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way to do that is with a rooted device.

try reading this answer: [Programmatic screencapture on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582603/programmatic-screencapture-on-mobile-device)

***EDIT 1:***

screen capture as video is the same is screen capture of only one image.

**EDIT 2:**

there are different apps that record video from screen such as [Screencast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencast) and [ShootMe](http://thedroidguy.com/2011/08/shootme-screen-grabber-most-popular-screenshot-utility-gone-from-android-market/). you can call them from within the app using the `startActivity(new Intent(String action));` with their action names.

for more read this: [Open third party app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752631/open-third-party-app)

Comment: screen capture as video is the same is screen capture of only one image.

Ya exactly the same i know how to convert running images to video but i am not gonna do this job cause i know would be a better api's to do this

Comment: did you read update number 2?

Answer (score 9):

I havn't tried this but think it can be done.
Kitkat provided new features and this is one of them
You can use this command to record screen as a video

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

You can find more details [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord)

you can execute the adb command from your app.
Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381828/is-it-possible-to-execute-adb-commands-through-my-android-app)

Comment: Unable to get output buffers (err=-38) Encoder failed (err=-38)

Comment: My Huawei phone seems removed  `screenrecord`.

Answer (score 7):

As per Android 5.0 (Lollipop), screen recording can be done without requiring root using the [MediaProjection package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html). An example of a recording activity can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/bf1e262/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/projection/MediaProjectionDemo.java).

Answer (score 1):

Summary from [longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336338/screen-video-record-of-current-activity-android/22984645#22984645):

Normal Android apps lack permission to capture the frame buffer (specifically, they aren't members of the AID_GRAPHICS group) so you CANNOT capture the screen from an Android app without some way of getting around the privilege issue. Apps do this in one of two ways: either by root or by starting a server via the ADB interface. So, it can be done without root, but you need to start you own server and connect to it from your app (and, obviously, safely handle the security implications of this)

Comment: Then using ADB i also can use [`MediaProjection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection) api **+** [some specific code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68402088/how-to-exclude-overlay-from-screenshot) to my overlay not appear on screenshot?