# Android - is it possible to video recoreding of android device screen?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i record the Android device screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680325/how-can-i-record-the-android-device-screen)

I read many articles but didn't find any solution..I need an app or something else for video recording of my device screen. I want to make promotional video of my other apps. Any help would be appreciated..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas from the top of my head:

- use emulator together with some screen capturing software for your computer
- if your device has TV-out, connect it to some screen that you can record

ddms is a tool that comes with Android SDK and you can use it to view the screen of your device, but the refresh rate on that is extremely slow.

There are also some screen recording applications in Google Play, but these require root access.

Comment: Thanks for reply...but I want to capture real device screen not for emulator..

Answer (score 0):

For this one thing you can do is

1)run application in you emulator and capture it using any [**Desktop Recorder**](http://camstudio.org/)
(I am doing this)

in order capture device screen

2)Use some application From [**Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zausan.zscreenrecorder&hl=en)

EDIT : See This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10680404/1450401)

Comment: just look at my above comment..

Comment: i just  mention 2 approaches  . i also says about a android application that may come in handy did you check that

Comment: Yes..I checked on market and found screencast but it requires root..