# How to record android screen?

Tags: android, screen-recording

I know the method of app screen recording by using android studio and successfully got the video for demonstration, but my question is how many other ways to record android screens without root my device ?
I want to add voice with my screen recording

Comment: Use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+.

Comment: Going to be difficult to do without rooting on version < 5.0.  Every app I've seen needs device to be rooted.

Comment: I've used GenyMotion's emulator recorder. Seemed to work fine.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using too for testing , but I think recorder is not available in free version

Comment: Ah, right. Last time I needed to record for free, I used [OBS](https://obsproject.com/)

Comment: Please see this link: [Record screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680325/how-can-i-record-the-android-device-screen)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple adb shell command:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/filename.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

The app [ScreenCam Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orpheusdroid.screenrecorder) works for me and doesn't require root (Android 8.1).