# How to get the intent filter of an android app

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have a third party dictionary app.  I want to open the dictionary from my app by passing a word. I want to know the **intent-filter** for the dictionary app in order to get the **action** (the app can perform) and the **data** (the diction can accept).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would to at the very least know the Package name of the third-party application to do this. This prevents developers from an unauthorized use of third-party applications.

These two links should be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752631/open-third-party-app

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422758/start-application-knowing-package-name