# How to open the youtube app using Intent

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

How can I launch youtube app using intent

```
         Intent intent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

         intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");    
         intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TKSW-VgVyM"));

         startActivity(intent);
```

The above code plays the video in youtube, but I want to open only youtube app, How Can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open it using the package name `com.google.android.youtube`

[start application knowing package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422758/start-application-knowing-package-name)

```
Intent.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
```

Comment: getLaunchIntentForPackage() is there such method?

Comment: I post a link, click on the link.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code needed for launching the Youtube app. Using this inside an onclicklistener is probably best.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
startActivity( launchIntent );
```