# open other app on button click from android appwidgetprovider

Tags: android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I would like to open another installed app by button/imageButton click from my app widget provider.
Here is my code,

```
 @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.activity_main);


        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageViewBus, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A specific app? If so, which app? Do you know the package name?

Comment: Yes a specific app. Yes I know the package name.

Comment: You just need to use the `PackageManager#getLaunchIntentForPackage()` method to get the `Intent` you're giving to the `PendingIntent`, as shown in the linked duplicate

Comment: can you give me some reference or code, which I can add in my code ?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31684505), as it's the closest fit to your situation. Change `"com.example.package"` to the package name for the app you want to open. Then, instead of calling `context.startActivity(launchIntent);`, use `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntent, 0)` to get the `PendingIntent` for your `Button`, and use that with `remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent()` just like you are in your posted code.

Comment: Its doesn't work. Can you please check my project? [GitHub](https://github.com/rifanalam/AndroidWidget.git)

Comment: You _don't_ want to call `context.startActivity(launchIntent)` there anywhere. Remove those calls. And notice my example uses `PendingIntent.getActivity()`, instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Comment: yes `PendingIntent.getActivity()` is working. Sorry for bother you and thank you for your kind help.

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it working. Cheers!